# Wrong typeName generated by wfs-t update request in xml

Tags: geoserver, openlayers, xml, wfs-t

I am editing features on a map using Openlayers 3 and Geoserver 2.8 linked to a postgresql Database. for adding features there is no problem but when it comes to update features I get a wrong xml code when I run writeTransaction, here is my code :

```
var wfst=new ol.format.WFS({
            featureNS: "myNameSpace",
            featureType: "myLayer"
        });
        var node = wfst.writeTransaction(null, [clone], null, {
            featureNS: "myNameSpace",
            featureType: "myLayer"
        });
        alert((new XMLSerializer()).serializeToString(node));
```

The xml generated is :

```
<Transaction xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/wfs" service="WFS" version="1.1.0" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/wfs http://schemas.opengis.net/wfs/1.1.0/wfs.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<Update typeName="feature:myLayer" xmlns:feature="myNameSpace">
<Property><Name>geometry</Name><Value>
<Polygon xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/gml"><exterior><LinearRing><posList>-7.741584777832031 33.52100372314453 -7.789649963378906 33.498687744140625 -7.758750915527344 33.45954895019531 -7.70416259765625 33.48186492919922 -7.741584777832031 33.52100372314453</posList></LinearRing></exterior>
</Polygon></Value></Property>
<Filter xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
<FeatureId fid="164"/></Filter></Update>
</Transaction>
```

the problem is here **typeName="feature:myLayer"** in the Update line of the xml, once I change feature to myNameSpace the request works fine.

and if I leave it like that I get a java.lang.NullPointerException error.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out a work around this error, it's not exactly what I hoped for but it gets the job done. So all I have to do is to modify the XML code for the update transaction in Javascript like this:

```
var str=new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(node);
var data=str.replace("feature:myLayer","myNameSpace:myLayer");
```

and then send data with an AJAX call to save the modification